# Segmentation fault while using strcat(num, num) to concatenate string to itself

Tags: arrays, c, string, segmentation-fault, string-concatenation

I used strcat function to concatenate "1" and "1" so that the result is "11" but I'm getting a segmentation fault.

My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
  char num[10] = "1";
  strcat(num, num);
  printf("%s", num);
}
```

Comment: You're lucky your machine has memory protection, otherwise you might have noticed every window filling up with `111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`! :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need two char[] one as source and other for destination, where destination array must be initialized and have enough space to accommodate source length.

```
#define DEST_SIZE 40

int main(){
  char num[10] = "1";
  char dest[DEST_SIZE] = "1"; //Destination with null characters after "1"
  strcat(dest,num);
  printf(dest);
  return 0;
}
```

For detailed explanation about different scenarios : [here](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/14213/how-to-play-with-strings-in-c/string-concatenation)

Comment: Ugh; answer not complete without following link. Please fix.

Comment: This is a fairly contrived way to solve the problem, requiring creation of an additional buffer. Better to use `memmove()`.

Comment: @mhawke For the level at which the question was asked, this is a fine answer.  Beginners have enough trouble getting their heads around C's definition of a string, and the limits of `str(n)cat` and `str(n)cpy`.  Bringing in `memmove` at this point would be rather overwhelming!

Comment: @SteveSummit: I see what you mean, maybe, but this question directly relates to those limitations, and the manifestation of program errors which result from them. Allowing a cheap workaround to slip by does not help the OP to understand the root cause, even though an offsite reference is provided.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the most likely implementation of `strcat`, don't do it. In general, it's a bad idea to pass a function the same parameter for both input and output. In fact, let's put this a little better. Unless the function says its defined, it's not defined, so don't do it.

Try this:

```
size_t n = strlen(num);
memmove(num + n, num, n + 1);
```

`memmove` is a nice function that's designed for overlapping inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `strcat` to concatenate two strings which overlap, which includes the case when they are the same string.

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat: "The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap."
- C17 7.24.3.1 (2): "If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
  undefined."

You'll have to write your concatenation routine by hand, or think about a solution based on `memcpy`.

Comment: I think you mean memmove, although most modern implementations got fed up with memcpy compatibility problems and just did memcpy -> memmove.

Comment: @Joshua: I was thinking of `memcpy(num+n, num, n)`, which don't overlap, and then adding the null terminator manually.  Your idea with `memmove` works too, of course, and is more streamlined.